# Stream MP3 file from Ubuntu source to Raspberry Pi using Python

Tags: python

I am a newcomer to Linux and Python and I am trying to attempt to stream an audio file (preferably MP3) from a Ubuntu source computer to a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian for immediate playback.

I have explored various options such as gStreamer, Live555, VLC player and PulseAudio. I have  also investigated TCP, RTP and RTSP. However I am struggling to get anything working properly. It seems as though I need to set up a RTSP Server using the computer and the Raspberry Pi as a RTSP client and I am not sure how to do this.

I'm wondering if anyone has any simple instructions or guides as to how to set up even a basic version of this with a specific MP3 file?

Answer (score -2):

Use MPC , works great. On fact, it's the only one I could get to work properly.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply! Any chance you could elaborate on MPC and how it is implemented or how you got it working properly?